# paper.js animation along a path

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm using paper.js and i'm trying to animate an item along a path I created...

```
//Path : 
 path = new Path();
 path.add(new Point(0,100), new Point(120,100), new Point(120,150));
//Item
 circle = new Path.Circle(0,100,4);
 circle.strokeColor = "#EEE";
```

And while animating (with onFrame()) I want the circle to follow the path... 
Does anyone know how to do that?
I didn't found it in the doc or on google....
I hope it's clear enough..

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Didn't test it yet, but it should be something like this.

```
// vars
var point1 = [0, 100];
var point2 = [120, 100];
var point3 = [120, 150];

// draw the line
var path = new Path();
path.add(new Point(point1), new Point(point2), new Point(point3));
path.closed = true;

// draw the circle
var circle = new Path.Circle(0,100,4);
circle.strokeColor = "#EEE";

// target to move to
var target = point2;

// how many frame does it take to reach a target
var steps = 200;

// defined vars for onFrame
var dX       = 0;
var dY       = 0;

// position circle on path
circle.position.x = target[0];
circle.position.y = target[1];

function onFrame(event) {

    //check if cricle reached its target
    if (Math.round(circle.position.x) == target[0] && Math.round(circle.position.y) == target[1]) {
        switch(target) {
            case point1:
                target = point2;
                break;
            case point2:
                target = point3;
                break;
            case point3:
                target = point1;
                break;
        }

        // calculate the dX and dY
        dX = (target[0] - circle.position.x)/steps;
        dY = (target[1] - circle.position.y)/steps;

    }

    // do the movement
    circle.position.x += dX;
    circle.position.y += dY;
}
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J9xgY/)

Comment: It works great (you even add an easing effect while being close to the target point) but i had to correct some little things, like circle.position.x instead of circle.x or  target[0] / target.x. To remove the easing effects, you have to decrement steps at the end of the frame and reinitialize it in the switch/case. (you can even make a ratio between steps and the current segment length in order to get the same speed on every segments...) Thanks a lot !

Comment: I see why the easing effect is there (didn't fully thought it trough), if you set dX and dY within the if statement it should no longer ease out. I will update the code.

Answer (score 4):

Solution to more control the speed :

- the move are proportional  to time
- can set the speed by pixel/second

http://jsbin.com/cukine/28/edit?html,output

```
var offset = 0;

circle.onFrame = function (event) {
  if (offset< path.length){
    circle.position =path.getPointAt(offset);
    offset+=event.delta*150; // speed - 150px/second
  }
  else {
    offset=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you care to add an explaination to your answer as to why it is different from the other older posts?

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because it relies on `Path.getPointAt(offset)`, rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Heres simple solution, i added a method to Point called `getPointAtPercent` so now you can just run that on your path to get where the point should be.

```
paper.Path.prototype.getPointAtPercent = function (percent) {
    return this.getLocationAt(percent * this.length).getPoint();
};
```

Heres an example of it working

http://jsfiddle.net/icodeforlove/uqhr8txp/1/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the:

```
path.getLocationAt();
```

method. This method accepts one parameter between 0 and 1, where 0 respresents the start and 1 the end of the path and returns a location.

You can use the:

```
path.length
```

property to calculate the different offsets of the parameter

```
steps = lengthOfSegmentToWalk / path.length
t = 0;
while( t <= 1  ){
    location = path.getLocationAt( t );
    t += step;
}
```

good luck

edit::

or you can use the

```
path.flatten( maxDistance );
```

method and read all the points from the resulting path...

Comment: Thanks ! I'll try this. 
But i've done another method which work too. I'm using path.getPointAt(). 
By calculating a percentage off my animation duration (fixed to 10s), 
I can get the next point of the path and so animate the item along it.
Thanks !

Comment: there are many ways, depends on your script, but on thing is for sure: you always have to deal with the parameter from 0 to 1, so if you want to animate over a chain of paths you need to combine them to get their total length.

Comment: You should use this instead of my predefined vars.

Comment: path.getLocationAt( t ) didn't work for me, it only took me to the next segment. path.getPointAt() on the other hand worked flawlessly!