# PaperJS - How to move along path and rotate along the path

Tags: javascript, math, paperjs

The examples shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12295072/paper-js-animation-along-a-path) show how to move an object along the path in Paperjs but how do I rotate them correctly along the path?

In the examples shown on the link above, people suggested by using a circle as an example. But once changed to a rectangle `new Path.Rectangle(new Point(20,20), new Size(20,20));` you can see that it moves along the path but does not actually rotate in the direction of the path.

How do I calculate the rotation and set it to my object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to calculate the rotation, you need to know the tangent vector to the path at the position of your rectangle.
This can be retrieved with [path.getTangentAt(offset)](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#gettangentat-offset) method.
Then, an easy way to animate the rotation of an item is to set `item.applyMatrix` to `false` and then animate the `item.rotation` property on each frame.

Here is a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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) demonstrating the solution.

```
// Create the rectangle to animate along the path.
// Note that matrix is not applied, this will allow us to easily animate its
// rotation.
var rectangle = new Path.Rectangle({
    point: view.center,
    size: new Size(100, 200),
    strokeColor: 'orange',
    applyMatrix: false
});

// Create the path along which the rectangle will be animated.
var path = new Path.Circle({
    center: view.center,
    radius: 250,
    strokeColor: 'blue'
});

// On each frame...
function onFrame(event) {
    // ...calculate the time of the animation between 0 and 1... 
    var slowness = 400;
    var time = event.count % slowness / slowness;
    // ...and move the rectangle.
    updateRectangle(time);
}

function updateRectangle(time) {
    // Calculate the offset relatively to the path length.
    var offset = time * path.length;
    // Get point to position the rectangle.
    var point = path.getPointAt(offset);
    // Get tangent vector at this point.
    var tangent = path.getTangentAt(offset);
    // Move rectangle.
    rectangle.position = point;
    // Rotate rectangle.
    rectangle.rotation = tangent.angle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for. Can you explain why it is important to set applyMatrix to false? I am still unclear how the applyMatrix attribute is for. On paperJS it only says that transformations aren't applied to the matrix property but directly...? What's the difference?

Comment: About apply matrix, for example in the case where you rotate a path, if it is set to `true`, the path points coordinates will be transformed to produce the rotation but the rotation angle will not be stored anywhere. 
If it is set to `false`, path points coordinates will not change and the rotation will be stored in the item matrix and accessible via the `rotation` property. This is more convenient in your context to simply animate this rotation property.